# Possible to ignore the Expression if it's null or empty without checking for null in an IF statement?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

Well, I have two expression `X , Y`

if flag is true then y has a expression

I need a `List<mylist> v = list.where(x).where(y).ToList();`

In this case if the y expression is null, it will throw an exception,

I know I can check for null before building the query, but in a huge query this can be a nightmare.

So is there any way or a value to tell the expression to be ignored when executing the expression ?

Comment: What do you expect from that `Empty` result? How should it behave when the calling code receive the `Expression<Func<,>>` instance?

Comment: I will edit my question and explain what  I am trying to do.

Comment: For god sake people, when are you going to start asking **correct** questions from the beginning? It's like my answer makes totally no sense now, regarding I answered good and was one of the first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add your own extension methods easily enough. It's not immediately clear whether you're using `IQueryable<>` or `IEnumerable<>` (your code wouldn't compile either way, due to casing issues and the fact that no `Where` method returns `List<T>`, and the fact that you're using `x` in the same statement you're declaring it) but you can handle both easily:

```
public static class NullSafeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> NullSafeWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return predicate == null ? source : source.Where(predicate);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> NullSafeWhere<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return predicate == null ? source : source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var results = source.NullSafeWhere(x).NullSafeWhere(y);
```

(Of course, it's only null-safe in terms of the predicate, not the source...)

Comment: This is a great a answer

Comment: You are missing the Generics in your method declaration. It should be `NullSafeWhere<T>`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the coalesce operator to provide another Expression when y is set to null:

```
list.Where(y ?? (() => true))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, calling the method with `Expression<Func<BAL.vw_BudgetRecord, bool>>` return type should always return an expression of that type.

Assuming on your example, you might want to return `bool?` (nullable bool) in case the use is not in SuperAdmin role.

If I'm right, you should change your method return type to `Expression<Func<BAL.vw_BudgetRecord, bool?>>`.

If not, you you change the return type simply to `Expression`; that will allow you to return both `LambdaExpression` and `DefaultExpression` as the same time.